# How do I find complex values that satisfy multiple inequalities?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I want to find $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $$|1-2a-2b| < 1 \quad \text{&} \quad |1-2a+2b| < 1$$ using mathematica. I tried to use `Solve[{Abs[1 - 2 a - 2 b] < 1, Abs[1 - 2 a + 2 b] < 1}, {a, b}]` but it never finishes the evaluation. How do I proceed?

Comment: with `FindInstance[Abs[1 - 2 a - 2 b] < 1 && Abs[1 - 2 a + 2 b] < 1, {a, b}]` one get `{{a -> 45/128 - (15 I)/32, b -> 0}}´.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ineq = {Abs[1 - 2 a - 2 b] < 1, Abs[1 - 2 a + 2 b] < 1};
```

As recommended by Daniel Huber, define intermediate variables

```
eq = {c == a + b, d == a - b};
```

The inequalities are equivalent to

```
sol = Reduce[Join[ineq, eq], {c, d}, {a, b}] /. (eq /. Equal -> Rule)

(* 0 < Re[a + b] < 1 && -Sqrt[Re[a + b] - Re[a + b]^2] < Im[a + b] < Sqrt[
  Re[a + b] - Re[a + b]^2] && 
 0 < Re[a - b] < 1 && -Sqrt[Re[a - b] - Re[a - b]^2] < Im[a - b] < Sqrt[
  Re[a - b] - Re[a - b]^2] *)
```

As recommended by rmw, use [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) to get specific examples,

```
(ex = FindInstance[sol, {a, b}, Complexes, 5]) // Column
```

[image]

Verifying that `ex` satisfy `ineq`

```
And @@ (And @@ ineq /. ex)

(* True *)
```

Comment: Why should *Mathematica* not be able to handle the original equations.  It is understood that making the substitutions simplifies things somewhat, but *Mathematica* cannot see that?

Comment: @mjw - Whether Mathematica "should" be able to solve any given problem is subjective. However, you can anticipate that you will encounter problems that it cannot **directly** solve. Many indirect approaches or workarounds are available.

Answer (score 4):

You may simplify the equations by setting:

```
c= a+b
d= a-b
```

Then we get the following equations:

```
eq={Abs[1 - 2 c] < 1, Abs[1 - 2 d] < 1}
```

that can be solved by `Reduce`

Reduce[eq, {c, d}]

[image]

Comment: Even better: `Abs[1-2c]<1` is the circle in the complex plane centered at 1 with radius 1/2, and similarly for `Abs[1-2d]<1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Reduce[{Abs[1 - 2 a - 2 b] < 1, 
    Abs[1 - 2 a + 2 b] < 1} /. {a -> x + I*y, b -> u + I*v} // 
  ComplexExpand, {x, y, u, v}, Reals]
```

The result is too long.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here is a human calculation.
Let $z_1=2a+2b$ and $z_2=2a-2b.$    NOT CODE Then $|z_k-1|<1$ for $k=1,2.$ Thus,
$$z_k=1+r_k(\cos \theta_k +i \sin \theta_k)$$
for $0\le r_k <1$ and $0 \le \theta < 2\pi.$
Consequently,
$a= \frac{1}{4} (z_1+z_2)$ and
$b= \frac{1}{4} (z_1-z_2).$

Answer (score 0):

A picture says more than thousand words ...

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[
Evaluate@ComplexExpand[{Abs[1 - 2 a - 2 b] < 1, 
  Abs[1 - 2 a + 2 b] < 1} /. {a -> a1 + I*a2, 
  b -> b1 + I*b2}], {b1, -5, 5}, {b2, -5, 5}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{a1, a2}]}, 
GridLines -> Automatic], {a1, -4, 4, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {a2, -4, 4, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image]

The intersection of both circles is the solution.